# Is there anything in the Django / Python world equivalent to SimplePie Plugin for Wordpress?

Tags: python, django, rss, django-templates, simplepie

I know that SimplePie itself is derived from UFP, but the features I'm wondering about are the post-processing features that are available in SimplePie for WordPress plugin:

http://simplepie.org/wiki/plugins/wordpress/simplepie_plugin_for_wordpress/processing

Can I find something similar to this for my Django application?

Can this be accomplished using Django inclusion tags?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [the universal feed parser](http://feedparser.org).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.djangosnippets.org/tags/rss/